# Java Логирование - разграничение

Tags: java, log4j

Для логирования я использую

```
<!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

в файле log4j.properties я использую такие настройки

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout
log4j.logger.org=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.logger.java=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.logger.javax=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.logger.com=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.logger.ws=WARN, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/my.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

в коде программы, для мониторинга ключевых моментов я использую log.debug(...)

Так вот в этот же вывод подпадает куча информации уровня Debug от всех пакетов, которые я задействую в коде.

Как мне разграничить мой дебаг и дебаг используемых пакетов?

Comment: Вот примеры для пропертей мне не попадались. (Да и самому не приходилось писать конфиг) Но на офф сайте есть целый раздел по разнообразным фильтрам https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html

Answer (score 1):

Из [мануала](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html):

```
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

используйте property вида log4j.logger.{имя пакета} для установки уровня логгирования

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос в части настроек log4j... я не разобрался как инвертировать, т.е. всем установить уровень WARN а для моего пакета DEBUG ?

Answer (score 0):

```
log4j.rootLogger=
```

Это настройка логера "по умолчанию", все пакеты, которые не указаны отдельно будут пользоваться этой настройкой. Соответственно, для вашего случая надо установить

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.logger.ИМЯ_ВАШЕГО_ПАКЕТА=DEBUG, file, stdout
```

Таким образом, все пакеты будут использовать уровень логирования и вывод, указанный в rootLogger, а для вашего пакета (или класса) будет действовать отдельная настройка.

Comment: так вот, я так пробовал и не получается... для моего пакета вывод тоже WARN...

Comment: я пробовал log4j.ru=DEBUG, file, stdout и log4j.logger.ru=DEBUG, file, stdout

Comment: у меня подозрение, что я не верно понимаю наименование своего пакета... как это проверить?

Comment: В вашем файле javа самой первой строкой объявлено наименование вашего пакета `package`?

Comment: тогда я все правильно делаю...

Comment: у меня package ru.test.start;

Comment: я пишу log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.ru=DEBUG, file, stdout

Comment: и вывод только WARN

Comment: Извините, правильно писать `log4j.logger.ИМЯ_ВАШЕГО_ПАКЕТА=...`

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout  И   
log4j.logger.ru=DEBUG, file, stdout

Comment: тоже не работает...